# Selenium: understanding wait

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The most common wait operation I've seen across the web is this

```
driver.get(url)
# apply a wait now
```

However, if I am in a REPL, I can see that `driver.get` is a blocking operation and nothing can be done until it is completed.

```
>>> driver.get(url)
# this blocks everything else until loading is complete
```

so how does wait work? If anything, shouldn't waits be declared before a `driver.get`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are getting confused by the time needed for accessing an url which is a blocking operation and the command wait implemented in Selenium.

Please refer to the documentation http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html

Selenium Webdriver provides two types of waits - implicit & explicit. An explicit wait makes WebDriver to wait for a certain condition to occur before proceeding further with executions. An implicit wait makes WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain amount of time when trying to locate an element.

Code from documentation:

An **explicit waits** in Selenium is code you define to wait for a certain condition to occur before proceeding further in the code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait # available since 2.4.0
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC # available since 2.26.0

ff = webdriver.Firefox()
ff.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(ff, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement")))
finally:
    ff.quit()
```

An **implicit wait** is to tell WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain amount of time when trying to find an element or elements if they are not immediately available.

```
from selenium import webdriver
ff = webdriver.Firefox()
ff.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds
ff.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")
myDynamicElement = ff.find_element_by_id("myDynamicElement")
```

Answer (score -1):

I was usually applying wait not to wait for the site to load, but to have all my js code loaded an executed. It can take several seconds, depending on size and complexity of your scripts.